# Create a button on Cascades with background image, BB-10

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I want to create a button using Cascades on Black Berry 10 development which has an image as a background and also possibly a text with white color. I found this class [button](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__button.html), but it seems to not support setting an image as a background on the button. What can I do? What are the alternate ways?
Maybe I should consider another library than Cascades for creating my UI??? any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe using an imageButton https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__imagebutton.html

Comment: hmm... yes, but the strange thing with that button is that it can't have 'text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Container {
        id:account
        signal buttonClicked()
        layout: DockLayout {
        }
        preferredWidth: 768.0
        topMargin: 40.0
        bottomMargin: 40.0
        ImageButton {
            id: addButton
            defaultImageSource: "image/button_normal.png"
            pressedImageSource: "image/button_press.png"
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            onClicked: {
               buttonClicked();
            }
        }
        Label {
            text: "Add"
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            textStyle {
                base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BodyText
                fontSize: FontSize.Small
                color: Color.create("#ffffff")
            }
            touchPropagationMode: TouchPropagationMode.None
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a button with both text and image by using the default Button class: cascades_button.html">https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*cascades*_button.html

Having a background image on the button with text over top is not really recommended. A button should be clear and easy to read. See the BlackBerry 10 UI Guidelines here: https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/design/bb10/UI_Guidelines_BlackBerry_10.pdf

If you really want to do it, you can always build a custom component in Cascades that has an image with a label over top.

Comment: Hi, I am actually creating this button as a custom control, using a Container (whose background is set to the image I like), and a label. But I want it to emit the behaviour of an ordinary button, meaning, when you click a normal button for example, you know when it kind of gets "selected/highlighted"? right? How to add this functionality to my button which I mentioned above??? Thank you.

Comment: ps. Here is the code:

 `Container {

    background: backgroundImagePaint.imagePaint
   
    Label {
        text: "Button text"
    }

    attachedObjects: [
        ImagePaintDefinition {
            id: backgroundImagePaint
            repeatPattern: RepeatPattern.Fill
            imageSource: "asset:///images/image.png.amd"
        }
    ]

}`

Comment: You would have to build that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue.

At the end, as PBernhardt said, I created a custom Container with an ImageView or a background image, and added a Label inside.
Then, I overrided onTouch to catch the different touch states (event.isDown(), event.isMove(), event.isUp()) and update the button graphics accordingly (text color and background image).

I'm using a Q_INVOKABLE method to bind with my C++ files.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly the same (although I didn't use Q_INVOKABLE for this button class I guess...)